# I'm having trouble with this sql query html/php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello I am new to web design so please excuse me if this looks like crap!

Ok what I am trying to do here is set up comments for each post.I figured a good way to do that would be to run a loop and assign `$save_id[]` to store the post id and a assign 
`$r <input type='text' name = *'".$r."'* style = 'width:478px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:-9px;'id='butt_box' placeholder='Respond?' title = 'Leave a response.'  />` which seems to work fine and returns the post id. When I submit the comment `$_POST['$s']` its not registering and the database is not updateing so I guess my question is can anyone see what I am doing wrong or specificly why  `if(isset($_POST['$s']))` fails?

```
enter code here $result =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE user ='$name'  ORDER BY time_date DESC LIMIT 100");
        $save_id =array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $save_id[] = $row["id"];
            $r = $row["id"];
            echo '<div id = "post">';
            echo '<img src = "'.$ico.'" style="margin: 0px" width = "48" height = "48" align = "left"/><h4>';echo $name.'</h4><h5>';echo $row["time_date"].'</h5><br>';
            echo $row["post"]. '</div>';
            echo "<form method='post' action=''>
            <input type='text' name = '".$r."' style = 'width:478px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:-9px;'id='butt_box' placeholder='Respond?' title = 'Leave a response.'  />

            <input type='submit' value='Post' class='tfbutton' style =' float:right;'>
            </form>";
        }


        if(!$result)
        {
            echo mysql_error(); 
        }
        foreach($save_id as $s)
        {

        if(isset($_POST['$s']))
        {
           echo $_POST['$s'];
            $mypost = isset($_POST['$s']) ?     
            $_POST['$s'] : '';

            if(isset($mypost) && strlen($mypost) > 0)
            {      
                $text = addLinks($mypost);
                $text = CheckEmotes($text);

                $p = $text;
                $emote = "none";
                $dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $sql = "INSERT INTO  `user_post_comments`(poster,post_id,responder,response,post_date)
                VALUES('$name','$s','$name',$text',$dt')";
                $rg = mysql_query($sql);

                if(!$rg)
                {
                    echo mysql_error(); 
                }
            }
            //header("Refresh:5; url=refresh.php");
        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $_POST['$s'] should be `$_POST[$s]` ($s without the quotes)

This is true. The reason behind this is because your $_POST is seeing your variable ($s) as **text**. Because of the quotes it thinks it is not a variable. Removing this should fix the problem.

Update, This line looks a bit odd:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE user ='$name'  ORDER BY time_date DESC LIMIT 100");
```

I hope your issue is fixed when the quotes are removed but if that is not the case id suggest changing your query like this:

```
$selectAllFromUser = "SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE user ='".$name."' ORDER BY time_date DESC LIMIT 100";
mysql_query($selectAllFromUser);
```

It might be possible that your query sees your `$name` variable as text as well. (Although i do not know the specifics of your version etc.)

(edit; it has been a long time but i think this should get you going).

```
enter code here 
$selectAllFromUser= "SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE user ='".$name."'  ORDER BY time_date DESC LIMIT 100";
$result =  mysql_query($selectAllFromUser);
        $save_id =array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
//not working with arrays often, but shouldnt it be required to specify a // position? 
            $save_id[] = $row["id"];
            $r = $row["id"];
            echo '<div id = "post">';
            echo '<img src = "'.$ico.'" style="margin: 0px" width = "48" height = "48" align = "left"/><h4>{$row["id"]}</h4><h5>{ $row["time_date"]}</h5><br>{$row["post"]}</div>';
            echo "<form method='post' action=''>
            <input type='text' name = '".$r."' style = 'width:478px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:-9px;'id='butt_box' placeholder='Respond?' title = 'Leave a response.'  />

            <input type='submit' value='Post' class='tfbutton' style =' float:right;'>
            </form>";
        }


        if(!$result)
        {
            echo mysql_error(); 
        }
        foreach($save_id as $s)
        {

        if(isset($_POST[$s]))
        {
           echo $_POST[$s];
            $mypost = isset($_POST[$s]) ?     
            $_POST[$s] : '';

            if(isset($mypost) && strlen($mypost) > 0)
            {      
                $text = addLinks($mypost);
                $text = CheckEmotes($text);

                $p = $text;
                $emote = "none";
                $dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//again using the $s without setting a position, is this valid?
                $sql = "INSERT INTO  `user_post_comments`(poster,post_id,responder,response,post_date)
                VALUES('{$name}','{$s}','{$name}','{$text}','{$dt}')";
                $rg = mysql_query($sql);

                if(!$rg)
                {
                    echo mysql_error(); 
                }
            }
            //header("Refresh:5; url=refresh.php");
        }          
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to bang the [use mysqli api](http://php.net/mysqli) drum, as @NathanKyle says he is new to programming it's silly to start using the [deprecated mysql API](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Comment: True but that is not the question, hence i did not mention it.

Comment: That's why added this as a comment and not an answer, for reference to @NathanKyle and other users.

Comment: No problems with it mate. however i still wonder about the arrays. haven't used those in a long time.

Comment: Thank you all lol I'm not new to programming just web design and removing the quotes and adding a missing quote in the query  did fix the issue. Ill start bangen that mysqli drumb you spoke of :D.

Comment: I Just noticed you layed out the whole code there is it a good practice in html php to {} enclose your variables in sql querys like that? I've done a bit of database stuff in c++ game programming but never enclosed my variables like that.

Comment: You shouldnt do it in any other language either. It is a nifty trick i stumbled upon by accident. It works like a charm, there is no need to use a chaotic amount of single and double qoutes and dots etc. However only use this in things like echo etc. also works in situations like this:

Comment: I cant find what i was looking for so im knda doubting myself now but i think it was HTML:  <input type="text" id="temp" value="<?php {row["id"]}; ?>"/>  I could be wrong since i cannot find the example i was looking for, but you should get the idea.

Comment: So to the question _is can anyone see what I am doing wrong or specificly why if(isset($_POST['$s'])) fails?_ I give you the correct answer and yet you mark this one? Cool someone upvated my answer so I've got 10 rep, not so cool I didn't get 25 rep for providing the correct answer.

Comment: You solved one problem yes, however this site is to help people. Not to answer just that whats asked, take your prize and get going. It is also for constructive feedback and if necessary additional code to fix other/underlying causes.

Comment: This was my first time posting on the site. Sorry to keep switching ah you are both right thank you I will keep in mind the rep points for future posts. I didnt realize I could upvote someone and also give someone else the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['$s']` should be `$_POST[$s]` (`$s` without the quotes)